# Return data matched on basis of query parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react hooks to render the data dynamically. I am performing two things:

a. fetching URL parameter from component's history props.

b. fetching state data from component's history props that returns me an array of objects something like:

```
current_data: Array(2)
0: {registration_data: {…}, company_name: "Test"}
1: {registration_data: {…}, company_name: "Sample"}
lastIndex: (...)
lastItem: (...)
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

What I need to achieve is, to render the data out of `current_data` object, that matched my URL query param. I am using `for loop` to iterate over my array. I know it's a noob question, but kinda stuck to get desired output.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const ViewRegistrations = (props) => {
    const [queryParam, setParam] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
        const queryParam = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search).get('registration');
        setParam(queryParam);
    })

    const [dataRecieved, setData] = useState( [] );

    useEffect(() => {
        const data = props.location.state.current_data;
        // const testData
        for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
            console.log(data[i] === queryParam)
        }
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ViewRegistrations;
```

The statement `console.log(data[i] === queryParam)` returns me boolean value everytime. I want the array data matched with query param to be stored in `dataRecieved` state. Please help to sort this out.

Comment: ```===``` is a logical operator so the result will be boolean. You should use the condition with ```if``` and push the ```data[i]``` into the required array.

Comment: I tried this: `for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
            if(data[i] === queryParam){
                testData.push(data[i])
            }
        }
        console.log(testData)`. This consoles me an empty array

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your question would be as follows
1. First of all get your desired queryParam on the mount of the component (I am also unsure about your usage of the useState hook, the second variable should be the first one with the 'set' added), like so:

```
const [queryParam, setQueryParam] = useState('');  
useEffect(() => {
const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search).get('registration');
            setQueryParam(query);
}, []) // don't forget to add an empty dependency array so it runs only once
```

Secondly, you then do your condition of match with another useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
const data = props.location.state.current_data;
if (data && queryParam)
for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
    data[i] === queryParam ? setDataReceived([...dataReceived, data[i]) : null;
  }
}, [queryParam])
```

And lastly you do whatever you want in terms of displaying them, you could achieve this with map in your component, something like

```
{dataReceived.length && dataReceived.map((data) => <whatever>data</whatever>)}
```

I am not 100% sure this is a working version, maybe some tweaks should be made, but this gives you an idea

Comment: I applied your approach with tweaks, but not able to get result. `const [dataReceived, setDataReceived] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => { const data = props.location.state.current_data;
        if (data && queryParam){
            for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
                return (data[i] === queryParam) ? setDataReceived([...dataReceived, data[i]]) : [...dataReceived];
           }      }}, [queryParam]);`

I am getting two errors: `Warning: An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. You returned:` and empty array as output

Comment: You don't have to return the setDataReceived inside the for loop, that's why you are getting the warning. What's the other error?

Comment: Removing `return` gives this `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`. And array is still empty. Its not matching the query param.

Comment: I don't know about the condition of ```data[i] === queryParam```. Does it ever equal to true?

Comment: I consoled `data[i] === queryParam`. But it returns false.When I console my data and queryParam, both of them gives me individual output. Data consoles array of objects at 0 and 1 indices. While queryParam returns 0 (required). Its not matching queryParam at 0 with data[0] value.  Can you explain this error?

Comment: Then the problem is in this condition inside the for loop and I feel like I don't have enough context to be able to debug it from here, but when you do - this will work